# How to determine total size of Amazon EC2 snapshots?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/355290/166311), it is not possible to determine the size of an individual Amazon EC2 snapshot, but they do provide "the total usage and cost numbers for all snapshots in the account."

Where can I see that total?

Background:  I'm trying to determine how encryption affects snapshot size. If I encrypt an EBS volume using dm-crypt, will EC2 still be able to compress it when making a snapshot, and will incremental blocks still help for subsequent snapshots?

The only way I could think to figure this out was to check on the size of snapshots, and since they are not available individually, I would have to check the total, make a snapshot, check the total again, etc.  BTW I'm still on the Free Tier so some billing info may be suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see that information in the Billing Management Console with the Usage Reports for the Elastic Compute Cloud service.
I can select "SnapshotUsage" for the different regions in there.

Comment: Thanks, but can't find that under Billing > Reports > EC2 Instance Usage Report.  Do I need to enable "Receive billing reports" into S3 as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/usage-reports.html)?

Comment: Maybe... I'm not sure as I activated nearly all (detailed) billing options to get as much information as possible to generate own reports and create scripts for the data.

Comment: I reviewed this again now that my free trial is over (and it might have worked before). Under Billing and Cost Management > Reports > Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud, I can select Usage Type = "EBS:SnapshotUsage" and download an XML or CSV report. I don't understand why the file is empty even though I have a snapshot? But at least I see the report now.